# ade20k dataset label issue

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm having a hard time understanding how to identify the labels in the ade20k dataset.

I was looking at the csv 
https://github.com/CSAILVision/sceneparsing/blob/master/objectInfo150.csv
and grabbed one example for floor , index 4

[image]

and then looked at one sample image `ADE_train_00000001.png` which in photoshop looks like the following when selecting a pixel on the the floor

[image]

in that screenshot, the floor has an rgb value of 3 for all channels, and assuming the index is used as the rgb value, shouldn't it be rgb(4,4,4) in photoshop?

I must be misunderstanding, can you help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns our photoshop was giving different values compared to Digital Color Meter (mac app)

Comment: Sir, thank you for sharing your conclusion about color systems. However, I am still a little confused about labeling in the ADE20K dataset? Have you found some better tutorial or explanation? Please, paste links to your sources, I would be grateful. Thank you

Comment: sorry, it's been a long time since i've worked with it. the best advice I can give is to look at some other more documented datasets first, then this one might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for an advice.